# visjs.org library : display only event dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, timeline, vis.js

By default visjs display every day on the timeline, is it possible to display only events dates? my goal is to make a simple timeline like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyPyh.jpg).

Is it possible to do that? Are there other alternative libraries?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you are asking for is pretty straight forward, how you would want to tailor it to look as close as possible to the reference will depend on you and what is supported. I have used visjs extensively for a web analytics project that we are currently building.

With the timeline API, after initialising the basic layout. You could simply add a few items in that timeline dataset of the events that you may be interested in.

The code should like something below

```
var container = document.getElementById('element');
```

Before anything you will first need to create an element, either directly in HTML or with JS. The choice is yours.

You will then need to grab the element so that the everything can be displayed directly in Element. After these first few steps you will need to initialise a dataset for the timeline. The dataset will be used to hold your data values (items), you can carry out a variety of operations on the dataset post rendering the chart.

```
 var items = new vis.DataSet([])
```

any options if you wish to add for the timeline.

```
var options = {}
```

lastly you have the actual timeline to create

```
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

now you need to the few items to the dataset that you had created earlier, this will be where your items you want to tag that will come in. There are a range of options right from what you want it to display to the styling of the item that will come in play.

```
items.add([
  {id: 1, text: 'item 1', date: new Date(2013, 6, 20), group: 1, first: true},
  {id: 2, text: 'item 2', date: '2013-06-23', group: 2},
  {id: 3, text: 'item 3', date: '2013-06-25', group: 2},
  {id: 4, text: 'item 4'}
]);
```

That would be one way of doing it. You can find more customisation options with how you want this items to look and behave [here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline.html#items)

Hope this helps.